# How to override default window close operation?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

In WPF I want to change default close behaviour of some window, so that when user clics red close button the window does not close, it merely hides (and call some method as well). How can I do that?

Comment: Now whose answer should I accept ?? Both are equally good...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try overriding OnClosing in Window.xaml.cs

```
private override void OnClosing( object sender, CancelEventArgs e )
{
     e.Cancel = true;
     //Do whatever you want here..
}
```

Comment: On my C# 4.0 setup this should be `protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 17):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) should help.

> Closing  can be handled to detect when a window is being closed (for example, when Close is called). Furthermore, Closing  can be used to prevent a window from closing. To prevent a window from closing, you can set the Cancel  property of the CancelEventArgs  argument to true.

And

> If you want to show and hide a window multiple times during the lifetime of an application, and you don't want to reinstantiate the window each time you show it, you can handle the Closing  event, cancel it, and call the Hide  method. Then, you can call Show  on the same instance to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true; // this will prevent to close
  `this.Hide();` // it'll hide the window
  // here now you can call any method
}
```