# Re-ask dialog when false

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog where the user gets to choose between some buttons, but the problem I'm experiencing now is that when the user closes the window (not choosing a button but using the x on the top right corner), the application shows the message but after that it crashes. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string[,] suppliers = new string[3,2] {{"xxx", "xxx"}, {"yyy", "yyy"}, {"zzz" , "zzz"}};


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ButtonPrompt buttonPrompt = new ButtonPrompt(suppliers, "Select supplier.");

        while (buttonPrompt.ShowDialog() != true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose one of the suppliers!");
        }

    }
}
```

ButtonPrompt.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ButtonPrompt : Window
{
    public ButtonPrompt(string[,] buttons, string question)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        buttonStack.Children.Clear();

        TextBlock questionBlock = new TextBlock();
        questionBlock.Text = question;

        buttonStack.Children.Add(questionBlock);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Button inputButton = new Button();

            inputButton.Name = buttons[i, 0];
            inputButton.Content = buttons[i, 1];

            inputButton.Width = 200;
            inputButton.Height = 60;

            inputButton.Click += inputButton_Click;

            buttonStack.Children.Add(inputButton);

            if (i == 0)
            {
                inputButton.Focus();
            }
        }


    }

    private void inputButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button inputButton = (Button)sender;
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buttonPrompt.ShowDialog()` returns true when the Window is closed.
Documentation says about the `Window_Closed`

> Once this event is raised, a window cannot be prevented from closing.

This means that you cannot set the `DialogResult` because it's already true and your while doesn't work.

You have three possibilities:

1. Override the `OnClosing` method like in [How to override default window close operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001525/how-to-override-default-window-close-operation) to prevent the window is closed from the GUI Button.
2. (My favourite) Override the `OnClosing` event like in http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx checking for your own conditions and adding `this.DialogResult = false`
3. Hide the close button of you Dialog Window from the XAML setting `WindowStyle=None`

**Update**: On the other side, put your while check out of your Main Window initialization, try with the Loaded handler so you're sure your Main component doesn't have troubles while coming up.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm now using the second possibility you recommended and it works like a charm! ;)