# WPF Window Closing does not work after Cancel

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have an issue that I can't seem to resolve via Google (likely because I'm not searching the right criteria). I have a Closing Event that checks if a button is enabled and pops a messagebox  with a result (Yes/No). If the user says NO, I get the desired results in the app; however, the X in the top right corner stops working. How to I "reinstate" the close button ("X" in the top right hand corner) so it works again if pressed (and also evaluates the logic again).

I tried this: [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001525/how-to-override-default-window-close-operation)

i don't think I want to play with Visibility of the window. The window doesnt go anywhere. They have dirty data and they need to fix it or have it auto saved.

What I have in the application is:

```
        private void DXWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        if (BtnPatSave.IsEnabled == false) return;
        if (MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.PatAcctMsgBox3, Properties.Resources.PatAcctMsgBox1,
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var patId = TbPatId.Text;
            var usl = new UnSetLockValue();
            usl.UnSetVal(patId);
            Log.Info("Patient Account is now unlocked by user: " + Environment.UserName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solved my own problem. In the loaded event, var b = LayoutHelper.FindElement(this, o => { if (o is Button) return o.Name == "PART_CloseButton"; return false; }) as Button; b.Visbility = Visibility.Collapsed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are using the MessageBox class. 
It disables the "X" button to allow the user only to provide the values you specify.
If you don't want this behaviour i think you have to create your own "MessageBox".